# Java - Adding and removing underlined text in a JButton on Hover

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton

I am using the following code to successfully have a hover effect of underlined text when the user mouses over a JButton.  This is working as intended.

When clicked, the JButton simply removes the current JPanel from the screen, and adds a new one to it.  This also works.

The problem is that when actually clicked, the hover effect of underlined text remains permanently on the JButton and does not go away when the mouse is moved.

I tried implementing `mouseClicked()` to have it remove the underlined effect when the button is clicked but this has no effect.  I could use some expert advice on how to keep the underlining effect in place, while removing it when the new JPanel is added through an action listener.

Snippet:

```
class MyAcctListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        totalGUI.removeAll();
        totalGUI.add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        totalGUI.add(myAcctPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        repaint();
        revalidate();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class HeaderMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
{
    Font original;

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
        original = evt.getComponent().getFont();
        Map attributes = original. getAttributes();
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
        evt.getComponent().setFont(original.deriveFont(attributes));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt){
        evt.getComponent().setFont(original);   
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        evt.getComponent().setFont(original); 
    }
}


private void createComponents() {
    MouseListener headerMouseListener = new HeaderMouseListener();
    acctButton = new JButton("My Account");
    acctButton.setFont(buttonFont);
    acctButton.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    acctButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    acctButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    acctButton.addMouseListener(headerMouseListener);
    ActionListener myacctListener = new MyAcctListener();
    acctButton.addActionListener(myacctListener);
}
```

Comment: Consider using the buttons `ButtonModel` instead of a `MouseListener`

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I was thinking of that sort of solution myself, but then I was thinking that it's hard for the model to get a reference to the object that uses it, since many such objects can use the same model object, and the model has no `getSource()` or similar method associated with it.

Comment: OK, I solved it, but with a kludge

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, you probably need some kind of "controller" which you can pass information to, it's not the most pleasant idea, but it does cover both mouse and keyboard operations :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per MadProgrammer's suggestion, one possible solution is to add a ChangeListener to the button's model, and check for `model.isRollover()` within that listener and behave accordingly.

For example:

```
button.getModel().addChangeListener(evt -> {
    ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) evt.getSource();
    Font btnFont = button.getFont();
    Map attributes = btnFont.getAttributes();

    if (model.isRollover()) {
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
    } else {
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, null);
    }
    btnFont = btnFont.deriveFont(attributes);
    button.setFont(btnFont);
});
```

But this is somewhat "kludgy" as it changes the state of the button from within its model listener.

Comment: That's great! That did indeed fix the the issue once the mouse listener was removed.  I don't mind kludgy as long as it works haha.  If you don't mind, What would this look like in its own named class rather than as an anonymous inner class?  I'd like to reuse it on multiple buttons without repeating code.

Answer (score 0):

> I could use some expert advice on how to keep the underlining effect in place, while removing it when the new JPanel is added through an action listener

Why would you remove it via the ActionListener? The button is still active. There is no reason the user couldn't click on the button again.

In any case your original logic is reasonable you just need to remove the underline attribute in the `mouseExited` and/or `mouseClicked` events. The key part you should have learned from Hovercraft's answer was how to remove the `underline` attribute from the font.

> I'd like to reuse it on multiple buttons without repeating code.

If you follow your own original solution then you can share the `MouseListener` because the source of the event will be the button:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
        Component button = evt.getComponent();
        Font font = button.getFont();
        Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
        button.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt){
    System.out.println("Exited");
        Component button = evt.getComponent();
        Font font = button.getFont();
        Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, null);
        button.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
    }
    /*
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        Component button = evt.getComponent();
        Font font = button.getFont();
        Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, null);
        button.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
    }
    */
};

JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
add( button1 );
button1.addMouseListener( ml );

JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
add( button2 );
button2.addMouseListener( ml );
```